# indesign attributes xml image

Tags: xml, image, adobe-indesign

I have an indesign file which is pulling in dynamic content from an XML file. Unfortunately when it brings in the updated images they are 100% ie not scaled to match the layout as edited from a previous import.
Is it possible to tag an image using attributes so the code would be similar to html

These attributes pull through but the image size an position remains unaltered.
I can do this by resizing all the images in photoshop but would rather do this on the fly using xml.
Could I somehow use xsl?
I"ve looked everywhere for days on this but can't find an answer.
Many thanks.

Comment: XSLT have no knowledge about byte streams sizes. There are CSS methods to accomplish this. Take a look into Stuart Nicholls' CSS Play [site](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/)

Answer (score 3):

thanks for your replies. I've found a solution. Basically you create an object style for your containing box, here you can set all kinds of options to an image as you would to a paragraph of type. Mac cmd/f7. Hope this saves someone some time...

Answer (score 0):

I've used XML in InDesign up to CS3.  From what I know, there is no way to size images pulling into InDesign via XML dynamically.  It doesn't allow you to map attributes for size and position of images.

Luckily, we worked with images of a pretty uniform size and position.  Our workaround has been to use a Photoshop action to size the images to what we need prior to pulling in the XML to Indd.  This workflow may not work for everyone, though.

One thing you can do is use relative paths for images.  You can setup the Indd template to link to a relative path (ex. /Images/) and use that path in the XML.  This always save me a lot of headaches in case I had to push XML to several designers.

Comment: In the solution you found, are you applying styling to the object style dynamically from the XML (width, height, position, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

InDesign always wants to import pictures at 100%. There are limited things you can do to avoid this behavior. In cs5 we finally have an option for Autofit. The picture frame is selected and you Autofit the picture to the frame. This option works on e basis of your selection within the Frame Fitting Options dialog. 
If all the pictures are being scaled in a similar fashion, you can always create an action within Photoshop to batch scale the imagesa.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the Object style has limited ability to do what you want. If you are always fitting the image into the box it will work. But if you want the image to align to one side or another, that's harder.

The best policy is to alway scale images before you need to use them. You can also write a JavaScript that can resize images based on specific criterion.